# Can two React distinct and mounted components communicate with each other using props?

Tags: reactjs

A simple example for explaining my question:

- `ButtonComponent` is a component mounted on `<div id="btn-container">` element
- `ModalComponent` is a component mounted on `<div id="modal-container">` element

So two components mounted on different elements in **different places in the page**, not sharing a common React element.

`ModalComponent` receive a prop named `isOpen` to trigger its visibility:

```
<ModalComponent isOpened={isOpened} />
```

The `ButtonComponent` should, in some way, pass the prop `isOpen` to the `ModalComponent` without sharing the same "root" component. Is this even possible?

Of course the "normal way" to do this would be a `ButtonPlusModalComponent` like the following:

```
export const ButtonPlusModalComponent = () => {
    const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);
        
    return (
      <>
        <ButtonComponent onClick={() => setIsOpened(true)} />
        <ModalComponent isOpened={isOpened} />
      </>
    );
};
```

I'm using React with a regular PHP application, so... not a complete "full" React application, only some parts and portions of the page are React components, no router at all.
So, I have that button somewhere in the page. That button should open the modal component, which is a... React component placed elsewhere in the page.

**EDIT**: explain why the question.

Comment: Did you try Redux *if your app uses it*? otherwise, you can use RxJs Observable for this

Comment: The main question is how you going to pass props to both components? I think you describing a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), try explaining with examples what you trying to do. Even if you can communicate without common parent, how you suppose to pass those props?

Comment: @DennisVash i explained why in my updated question.

Comment: Context or redux

Comment: @LuisMendes535 I dont' think I can use context, because (see my edits) I have some react components rendered in the page but not a "single" React application. So where would you place the context provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **both** component to share a common parent, thats how React works as [Data Flows Down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down).

If you can, couple them into the same tree and use common solutions like [`Context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

But, you describing a situation where the components are decoupled, so in order to have a common parent **and** mount a component into  another HTML element, you need to use [`React.Portal`](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

Therefore you need one component to mount the other using Portals:

```
<body>
  <div id="modal-container"></div>
  <div id="btn-container"></div>
</body>
```

```
const Modal = ({ open }) => open && <>Modal</>;

const App = () => {
  const [open, toggleOpen] = useReducer((p) => !p, true);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggleOpen}>toggle</button>
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <Modal open={open} />,
        document.getElementById("btn-container")
      )}
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("modal-container")
);
```

[image: Edit Yet another React Portal Example]

Comment: So I think it's what I was looking for, portals :) quite clear to me. Can the same portal (the container) render more than 1 component? I.e. if one calls ReactDOM.createPortal multiple times, the all render or the last one wins?

Comment: They just stack, you can check it in the sandbox.